# How to create a bootable disk

Tags: bootloader, bootable

I'm trying to create a bootable disk from an ISO that is bootable. I should be able to just burn this and it will boot a machine with no OS, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you trying to create bootable win7/8 installer?
If yes, get UltraISO and then openup your ISO with that program, then goto bootable->Write disk image, after that you will be able to bootup your flashdrive